# PAGINATION in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am new in MDX and currently struggling in this. I badly need help on how to get the total count of customers based on the WHERE clause. Please see my query below. I am trying to implement pagination so I need the total count to get the number of pages to be displayed. Is that possible?

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[DS_TY] AS 
  '([Transaction Type].[All Transaction Type].[Daily Sales], [Measures].[TY])' 
MEMBER [Measures].[ST_TY] AS 
'([Transaction Type].[All Transaction Type].[Stock Transfer], [Measures].[TY])' 
MEMBER [Measures].[IS_TY] AS 
  '([Transaction Type].[All Transaction Type].[IServ], [Measures].[TY])' 
MEMBER [Measures].[TOT_TY] AS 
  '([Transaction Type].[All Transaction Type], [Measures].[TY])' 
MEMBER [Measures].[DS_LY] AS 
  '([Transaction Type].[All Transaction Type].[Daily Sales], [Measures].[LY])' 
MEMBER [Measures].[ST_LY] AS 
'([Transaction Type].[All Transaction Type].[Stock Transfer], [Measures].[LY])' 
MEMBER [Measures].[IS_LY] AS 
  '([Transaction Type].[All Transaction Type].[IServ], [Measures].[LY])' 
MEMBER [Measures].[TOT_LY] AS 
  '([Transaction Type].[All Transaction Type], [Measures].[LY])' 
MEMBER [Measures].[2] AS 
  'iif([LY]=0 Or [LY]=Null, Null, ([TY] - [LY])/[LY])' 
MEMBER [Measures].[4] AS 
  '[1] - [TY]' 
MEMBER [Measures].[6] AS 
  '[5] - [TY]' 
SET smeasures AS 
'{[DS_TY],[ST_TY],[IS_TY],[TOT_TY],[DS_LY],[ST_LY],[IS_LY],[TOT_LY],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]}' 
MEMBER [Measures].[TY] AS 
  '[Measures].[Gross Up Sales YTDTY Amt (Allocation)]' 
MEMBER [Measures].[LY] AS 
  '[Measures].[Gross Up Sales YTDLY Amt (Allocation)]' 
MEMBER [Measures].[1] AS 
  '[Measures].[Quota Amt YTDTY (Allocation)]' 
MEMBER [Measures].[3] AS 
  '[Measures].[%Perf YTDTY GrossUp (Allocation)]' 
MEMBER [Measures].[5] AS 
  '[Measures].[Quota Annual Amt TY (Allocation)]' 
SELECT smeasures ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY ORDER ( 
  { 
    [Client Customer].[Client Customer].[Customer].members 
  }, 
  [Client Customer].currentmember.name, 
  basc 
) ON ROWS 
FROM [CClient] 
WHERE ( 
      { 
        [Time].[Time].[Year].[2020].[November] 
      }, 
      [Transaction Type].[All Transaction Type], 
{[Client Org].[Level 02]}- 
DESCENDANTS({[Client Org].&[D2_BTR2099_01], [Client Org].&[D2_DTR2099_99], [Client Org].&[D2_GTR2099_02]}) 
    )
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Subset for paging. Let me walk you through an example. Its based on Microsoft AdventureWorks

So I want to see the INTERNET SALES AMOUNT of all PRODUCTS in FRANCE for 2012.

```
select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}on 0,

order (
filter({[Product].[Product].[Product]},[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]>0)
,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],desc)
on 1 
from 
[Adventure Works]
where 
([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012],[Geography].[Country].&[France])
```

This result is [image]

These are 94 rows, since the header is also counted so SSMS shows 95

[image]

Now lets change the query just to return the number of rows without returning actual rows. For this we use a calculated measure, which will have the entire set expresion of your rows axis. We then apply count function on this

```
---total Row Count 
with member 
Measures.ResultSetCount 
as
(filter({[Product].[Product].[Product]},[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]>0)).count

select Measures.ResultSetCount  on 0
from [Adventure Works]
where 
([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012],[Geography].[Country].&[France])
```

[image]

We now know we have 94 rows. Now Lets returns them in pages of 10.

```
------Paging 
select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}on 0,

subset(
order (
filter({[Product].[Product].[Product]},[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]>0)
,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],desc)
,0,10)
on 1 
from 
[Adventure Works]
where 
([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012],[Geography].[Country].&[France])
```

[image]

The result is for page 1, replace the "0" with 1, before 10 in ",0,10)" you will have page 2 and so on.